# Update Logged in user data in Laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to update the profile of logged in users in laravel5. I have the name of the logged in user through the session but then when I want to put the new input data to the old user data, it didn't work. I think I am having a problem in getting input user data into the controller function.

Controller:

```
public function updateProfile(Request $req) {
    $name =  Session::get('admin-name');
    $user = DB::table('admin')->where('name',$name)->first();
    return dd($req->input('admin-name'));

    if($req->input('admin-name')!= null) {
        $user->name = $req->input('admin-name');

    }
    if($req->input('admin-email')!= null) {
        $user->email = $req->input('admin-email');
    }
    if($req->input('admin-address')!= null) {
        $user->email = $req->input('admin-address');
    }
    if($req->input('admin-mobile')!= null) {
        $user->mobile = $req->input('admin-mobile');
    }
    if($req->input('admin-dob')!= null) {
        $user->dob = $req->input('admin-dob');
    }
    $user->save();
    return view('admin-profile')->with('update-response','Profile Updated successfully');}
```

View:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('admin-edit-profile')}}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}                            
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="admin-name">Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="admin-name" id="admin-name" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="admin-email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="admin-email" id="admin-email" placeholder="Enter your email"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="admin-address">Address:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="admin-address" id="admin-address" placeholder="Enter your address"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="admin-mobile">Mobile:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="admin-mobile" id="admin-mobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile number"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="admin-dob">Date of Birth:</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="admin-dob" id="admin-dob" placeholder="Enter your Date of Birth"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="admin-pic">Your Profile pic:</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="admin-pic" id="admin-pic" placeholder="Your Profile pic"/>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" id="submit" class="btn btn-info"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-info"/>
                    </form>
```

Routing is working fine. But I think the problem is with the controller function.I am getting an error:

> Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Comment: You missed the `name` attributes of input fields.

Comment: i have added but didn't work either.

Comment: getting the error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Answer (score 0):

> Getting the error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

`save()` in Eloquent method, so use Eloquent:

```
$user = Admin::where('name', $name)->first();
```

Comment: It is throwing error - Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin' not found

Comment: @user9332352 add the `Admin` class at the top of your controller like this `use App\Admin;`

Comment: new error: Creating default object from empty value

Answer (score 0):

in your case you should use eloquent by replace

`$user = DB::table('admin')->where('name',$name)->first();`

with

```
$user = Admin::where('name', $name)->first();
 if(!$user){ return "can't find this admin the name is null or not saved in DB"; }
```

Certainly you should import your `Admin` model

**note:** be sure  if `admin-name` is Session key

Comment: getting same error :Creating default object from empty value

Comment: and when i use dd($user) , it returns null

Comment: are  you replace first() with findOrFail()?

Comment: your session value is missing and  can't find "admin-name" key in session

Comment: Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::findOrFail(), 0 passed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel/blog/app/Http/Controllers/AdminProfileController.php on line 24 and at least 1 expected

Comment: but when i use dd($name) it return user name

Comment: i edited my answer  ...  if  dd($name)  return user name please check 
 if user is exits in DB manualy